# wysiwyg xhtml text area with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: editor, richtextbox, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I have a web-based table editor with many textarea's. The textarea's contain HTML content. I would like the users to be able to edit them in WYSIWYG style. Since my users love to use the keyboard, I would like it to have a simple way to add keyboard shortcuts, including shortcuts for adding div's with custom class names.

This: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/ comes close to what I need, the only problem is that it's not WYSIWYG.

This: http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/ is also close, but does not have keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious answer is [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo). Besides all the built-in shortcuts (Press Alt-0) you can add more commands with the API.